# For any finite partitions of the plane and a finite set A, does there exist a set in the partition that has a similar copy of A?

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry, examples-counterexamples

The original statement of the problem is the following:
For any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $A \sim B$ if and only if $A$ can be scaled, translated and rotated into $B$.
For any finite partition of $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is $P_i \subset \mathbb{R}^2, \cup_{i = 1}^{N} P_i = \mathbb{R}^2, \forall i \neq j, P_i \cap P_j = \emptyset, $ and for any finite set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, there exists $P_i$ such that there exists a subset $B \subset P_i$ and $A \sim B$.

Obviously each $P_i$ cannot have any cells in it, so intuitively speaking a counterexample must split the plane into very fine pieces.
However a lot of such constructions (Example: $\mathbb{Q}^2$, taking basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, etc..) doesn't seem to be extendable to the whole plane.

I have tried some positive proofs by induction on the number of points of $A$, but have found no real progress.
Any partial result (Example: axiom of choice, assuming unsolved conjectures, weaker cases) will be very appreciated.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? If it's a textbook exercise, what topic(s) have been covered in the chapter that seem relevant?

Comment: Someone in my school's community asked this question without explanation. I guess he/she devised it by himself/herself. I've never seen a question like this before. The posted tone indicated he/she didn't know the answer

Comment: Do you know what the answer to the question is for $\mathbb{R}$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true, and you don't need rotation, just dilation and translation. This is a classical result known as Gallai's theorem or the Gallai–Witt theorem. You can find a proof in [this paper by Roger D. Maddux.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.1038)